# Creating a getCounter() method to count up when the method is called

Tags: java, count, counter

I am trying to create a `getCounter()` method which will count upwards each time the `getCounter()` method is called. For example if the method is called 10 times then the output should be: 1,2,3...10.

This is the current code I have:
Main class:

```
public class JavaLab5 {
    public static final int DEBUG = 0;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student s[] = new Student[10];


        s[0] = new MathStudent("Smith");
        s[1] = new MathStudent("Jack");
        s[2] = new MathStudent("Victor");
        s[3] = new MathStudent("Mike");
        s[4] = new ScienceStudent("Dave");
        s[5] = new ScienceStudent("Oscar");
        s[6] = new ScienceStudent("Peter");
        s[7] = new ComputerStudent("Philip");
        s[8] = new ComputerStudent("Shaun");
        s[9] = new ComputerStudent("Scott");

        for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
            System.out.print(loop);
            System.out.println(s[loop].getSubjects());
        }

    }

}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student {
    String name;
    int count 
    public static int instances = 0;

    //Getters
    public  String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setName(String name) {
        if (JavaLab5.DEBUG > 3) System.out.println("In Student.setName. Name = "+ name);
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor. Populates name,age and gender 
     * with defaults
     */
    public Student() {
        instances++;
        this.name = "Not Set";
    }

    /** 
     * Constructor with parameters 
     * @param name String with the name
    */
    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Destructor
     * @throws Throwable 
     */
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        //do finalization here
        instances--;
        super.finalize(); //not necessary if extending Object.
    } 

    public void getCounter() {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
    }
    public String toString () {
        return this.name; 
    }

    public String getSubjects() {
      return this.getSubjects();
    }
}
```

My question is how I can implement such a method to call it from my Main class.

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: @YounesM want to create an upward counting counter everytime the getCounter() method is called.

Comment: @anon1234 that's a description of what you want to do, not a question. Ask a question, please.

Comment: I'm voting to close as it still isn't exactly clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: @domdom it isn't clear what Im asking yet you manage to provide me with an answer and then now deleted it, and also all these users have managed to give me an answer.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I noticed that I misunderstood your (non-existent) question. First I wanted to edit it, then I realized that I'm still not sure what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: You should look at adding a Logger to your code.  Work with your teacher on how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to implement such a method, try this:

```
private int myCounter = 0;

//Use this line instead if you want a global counter for all Studen-Objects
//private static int myCounter = 0;

public void getCounter() {
  System.out.println(myCounter);
  myCounter++;
}
```

Comment: How would I call this method in the main class?

Comment: @anon1234 No offence but if you don't know how to call a method, you might want to consult some books or tutorials before you consult SO.

Comment: You need a reference to a Student-Object to call it, so fo example: `s[0].getCounter();`

Comment: Note that every object has it´s own counter, if you want to have a global counter for all Student-Objects you need to declare the `myCounter` as static

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities :

You wish to count every time you call the function and have a fresh counter for every object

```
   public class Student {
        String name;
        int count =0; // every object of class Student will have its own `count`
        //rest of the declrataions / functions
        public void getCounter() {
            System.out.println(++count);
        }
}
```

You wish one counter that counts up every time you call getCounter irrespective of the number of objects you have of the class `Student`

```
public class Student {
String name;
static int count = 0; //static so that multiple object instances of the class share the same `int count`
//rest of the declrataions / functions
public void getCounter() {
    System.out.println(++count);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply remove for loop in getCounter method

change :

```
public void getCounter() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    count++;
    System.out.println(count);
}
}
```

to :

```
public void getCounter() {
    System.out.println(count);
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You state you want to count how many times a method was called. In addition you want to print a sequence of all numbers starting from `1` to the number of counted method calls. Addressing concurrency, my solution would be:

```
public class CountTracker {

    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public static int count() {
        return counter.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public static void printCounter() {
        int count = counter.get();
        if (count == 0) return;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) builder.append(i).append(",");
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(builder);
    }
}
```

The method `count()` represents the method you want to track. I have no idea why your solution does include a class `Student`.